# Unable to receive utm parameters after successful installation of app

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

Hey everyone i  have implemented google analytics in  my application it was working fine in the starting . but now i am not able to track data for my different campaigns.

After testing and following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) provided by google for testing google  analytics implementation  .I am able to get the log "GAv4    : Received installation campaign: " Which means implementation has no issues . but still no data is being reflected on my  analytics dashboard.

my custom broadcast receiver

public class MyReferralReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(Application.isTrackingEnabled()) {
        ReferralReceiver localyticsReferralReceiver = new ReferralReceiver();
        localyticsReferralReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    // passing install referrers to uninstall io .
    InstallReferrerReceiver uninstall_tracker = new InstallReferrerReceiver();
    uninstall_tracker.onReceive(context , intent);


    // Google tracking receiver
    CampaignTrackingReceiver campaignTrackingReceiver = new CampaignTrackingReceiver();
  campaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);

}}
```

Any type of help would be appreciated

PFA  below which shows [the log which i am recieving while testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXVBL.png)

Comment: It can take up to a day for GA data to be processed. Have you check your analytics dashboard after a day?

Comment: yes i have done the same dashboard is unable to reflect data after  24 hours .